# store checkbox value to mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, row, storage

I have problem in storing checkbox values in mysql db . How can I fix this code to store all checked values?

There are seven different columns in type must be stored in the database when you checked for rows

This part of the code is responsible for fetching data from the database and put it in a table:

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
        print  
            "<tr>    <td><input type='checkbox' name='check[]'  value='
            ".$row['course_id'].",
            ".$row['course_name'].",
            ".$row['day'].",
            ".$row['place'].",
            ".$row['hour'].",
            ".$row['type'].",
            ".$row['instructor_name']."' /></td>

            <td>{$row['course_id']}</td>
            <td>{$row['course_name']}</td>
            <td>{$row['day']}</td>
            <td>{$row['place']}</td>
            <td>{$row['hour']}</td>
            <td>{$row['type']}</td>
            <td>{$row['instructor_name']}</td>

             </tr>"; 
      }


     print "</table>
           <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit'>
           </form>";
```

This part of the code responsible for storing the data in databases

```
     if(isset($_POST['check'])){     
    $returned = $_POST['check']; 
    $office = array('course_id','course_name','day','place','hour','type','instructor_name');
    $values = array();

    foreach($office as $selection){ 


$insert1 ="INSERT INTO initial_registration
(course_id,course_name,day,place,hour,type,instructor_name) 
SELECT *
FROM offerd_course";



    mysqli_query($insert1) or die(mysqli_error());  

    } 
 }
```

Comment: For one thing, you're mixing MySQL APIs with `mysql_query($insert1) or die(mysql_error());`, where further up, you're using `mysqli_fetch_array`. Show us the error you're getting. Plus, who knows which API you're using to connect with.

Comment: The problem here is that no results
Does not store data in databases

Comment: `mysqli_query($con,$insert1)` - `mysqli_error($con)` - you need to pass DB connection.

Comment: ^^^^^ So, any luck so far?

Comment: There was an answer given below, have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I tried and did not work
Thank you for your reply

Comment: It's not just copy paste here on stackoverflow. I think you are still missing some basic knowledge about php/mysql. Maybe it's smart to check out some small tutorial like: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_insert_php.htm I am sure then you can solve your problem with the help of my answer! Goodluck :-]!

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort

Answer (score 0):

I think your whole setup is not good, here is some code to get you started:

first print all courses

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
    print  
        "<tr>    
        <td><input type='checkbox' name='row_checked_".$row['course_id']."'  value='1' /></td>
        <td>{$row['course_id']}</td>
        <td>{$row['course_name']}</td>
        <td>{$row['day']}</td>
        <td>{$row['place']}</td>
        <td>{$row['hour']}</td>
        <td>{$row['type']}</td>
        <td>{$row['instructor_name']}</td>
        </tr>"; 
  }
```

And then for the inserting part:

again go through all courses to see which courses have been 'checked'

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
    if(isset($_POST['row_checked_'.$row['course_id']]) && $_POST['row_checked_'.$row['course_id']]==1){
       //insert query here
    }
}
```

Your insert query is also messed up a bit, Why do you want to insert the whole course into initial registration? You'll rather want to do something like this:

```
$insert1 ="INSERT INTO initial_registration (course_id,STUDENT) VALUES ($row['course_id'],$some_student_id_value)";
```

Comment: I tried it did not work does not save data in databases

Comment: You'll want to debug by printing what happens. if you do a print_r($_POST) does it receive the post values?

Comment: Array ( [row_checked_105] => 1 [Submit] => Submit )
//105 =course_id

Comment: thats good! So your insert query is wrong. Maybe look here for more info: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp